# PHP OOP - How to check if user is logged in without making a database connection (class User)

Tags: php, oop

I've got a class User with some ordinary methods and a constructor that passes a $pdo object. There's also a method called **isLogged()** and it just checks if necessary session variables are set.

But what if I want only check if user is logged, without making a db connection?

```php
// I need to check if user is logged here but it requires including db.php
require 'includes/db.php';

$user = new User($pdo);

if (!$user->isLogged()) {
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit;
}

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    // POST validation
    // ...
    // That is the place where DB connection should be made
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the user logs in you will need to set a session variable that marks the user as logged in, then you check for that variable whenever you need to

```
function private setLoggedIn() {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['isLoggedIn'] = true;
}

function public checkLoggedIn() {
    if ($_SESSION['isLoggedIn']) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I know, but in which class should I create these functions? User? If so, while creating an object, I will still need to connect to database.

Comment: You could have a class called Login extends User. In Login include your db call and check username / password when the user logs in. In User include the functions in my answer above. Use $this->setLoggedIn() when the user is authenticated